# Ethernet not working on Ubuntu 18.04.5 LTS

Tags: networking, network-manager, ethernet

My ethernet cable is not recognized anymore, on neither Network (work/home).
`ifconfig`

```
enp0s31f6: flags=4099<UP,BROADCAST,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
        ether 54:e1:ad:b5:f1:63  txqueuelen 1000  (Ethernet)
        RX packets 0  bytes 0 (0.0 B)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 0  bytes 0 (0.0 B)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0
        device interrupt 16  memory 0xec200000-ec220000  

lo: flags=73<UP,LOOPBACK,RUNNING>  mtu 65536
        inet 127.0.0.1  netmask 255.0.0.0
        inet6 ::1  prefixlen 128  scopeid 0x10<host>
        loop  txqueuelen 1000  (Local Loopback)
        RX packets 6261  bytes 596363 (596.3 KB)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 6261  bytes 596363 (596.3 KB)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0

wlp4s0: flags=4163<UP,BROADCAST,RUNNING,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
        inet 10.111.35.119  netmask 255.255.252.0  broadcast 10.111.35.255
        inet6 fe80::ba41:664a:2235:d79a  prefixlen 64  scopeid 0x20<link>
        inet6 2001:700:200:f132:525b:e148:8c18:17d3  prefixlen 64  scopeid 0x0<global>
        inet6 2001:700:200:f132::13bb  prefixlen 128  scopeid 0x0<global>
        inet6 2001:700:200:f133:356d:2dde:4ce:2297  prefixlen 64  scopeid 0x0<global>
        ether bc:a8:a6:9a:c7:84  txqueuelen 1000  (Ethernet)
        RX packets 106167  bytes 123265102 (123.2 MB)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 26746  bytes 6175687 (6.1 MB)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0
```

I already tried fiddling with `sudo vi 10-globally-managed-devices.conf`
`sudo service network-manager restart`

the content of the `sudo vi /etc/network/interfaces` is

```
iface enp0s31f6 inet loopback
```

tried `sudo ifdown enp0s31f6` and `sudo ifup enp0s31f6`

Comment: Cables go bad. Try a different cable.

Comment: I tried 3 different cables on 2 different networks

Comment: Then seems like your ethernet port/hardware itself has gone bad. It's rare, but it does happen on occasion.

Comment: I had the same issue. My ethernet cable went to a faulty switch. Directly connecting to the router resolved it, switch has to be replaced or reconfigured. The switch went bad overnight.

Answer (score 1):

> ```
> the content of the sudo vi /etc/network/interfaces is
>
> iface enp0s31f6 inet loopback
> ```

Please change the file to:

```
auto lo
iface lo inet loopback
```

Reboot and tell us if there is any improvement.

Comment: Good one. +1 :-)

Comment: exactly the same result the ethernet cable is not recognized at all